# Priority inheritance from parent process by new process in linux

Tags: process, linux-kernel, initialization

In Linux when a new process is created, it inherits the `normal_prio` value of it's parent process for it's `static_prio`. Where does this actually happen??

Is it done in `dup_task_struct()` function or in `copy_process()` function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually happens in [sched_fork](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched.c#L2972) which is called by [copy_process](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1042)

The parent's priority is transferred into the child initially something like this

```
p->prio = current->normal_prio;
```

where p is child's `task_struct` and `current` points to parent.

And then `normal_prio` is modified like this

```
p->prio = p->normal_prio = __normal_prio(p);
```

`__normal_prio(p)` finally boils down to something like

```
return p->static_prio;
```

Check out the 2 links I've added to explore more.

Comment: Thanks.. And is there any tool or way using which i can trace these things?? I mean any way by which I can trace the flow of, how a process is created and scheduled??

Comment: `kdb` and `kgdb` ( You can google them ) are the two debuggers available for debugging the Linux Kernel. Debugging the Linux kernel is no simple task. I would rather suggest reading some good books on Linux/Linux Kernel. Ex-the one by Robert Love. Also use http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ for ready reference

Comment: Is there any tracing tool which would show me the functions copy_process and sched_fork being called, when a process is started?? strace or ptrace will they help me??

Comment: Careful use of `ptrace` should help